# Creating Thick Neatline using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts

How would I change the thickness of a neatline using ArcGIS 10.2.1?

Alternatively, if neatline thickness can't be changed, how would I draw it with a rectangle with no fill and rounding?

The map view is a rectangle occupying all but the top and the bottom of the neatline which have the title and legend respectively.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Comment: Question is very specific - how to to create a thick rectangle with rounded corners using either use neatline or rectangle .

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In arcmap Layout, Everything about outline can be changed using options in **View -> Data Frame Properties -> Frame**.

Just right click on the border and click properties and change the outline as you want to do. For example adding a rounding percentage will create rounded corners.

[image]

For neatline,
Go to Insert -> Neatline to insert a neatline in the Layout, Make sure **Create Separate neatline element** is checked. Before inserting click "Advanced" button in the left bottom corner of the window. There you can change thickness, rounded corner, color etc...

[image]

Comment: Which setting in Frame to change neatline thickness?

Comment: Added above with screenshot!

Comment: Our corporate network blocks access to the images but your description is clear. Somehow I didn't have access to these options with the way I inserted the neatline previously.